# Scan the properties of files on an excel sheet by Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, filereader

I have a task that requires to scan the property of all the files indicated by certain directories where the files are stored. I need my code to read the following line of information separated by the delimiter "," stored in a .txt file as follows (the directory is made up by myself on my own device and I went ahead making up some blank .xlsx files to test my code:

```
Jakarta,C:\\temp\Hfolder,C:\temp\Lfolder
```

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
$LocContent = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Location.txt" # -Header $fileHeaders
ForEach($line in $LocContent){C:\temp\test1.csv -NoTypeInformation 
#split fields into values
      $line = $LocContent -split (",")
      $country = $line[0]
      $hDrivePath = $line[1]
      $lDrivePath = $line[2]
      Get-ChildItem $hDrivePath -force -include *.xlsx, *.accdb, *.accde, *.accdt, *.accdr -Recurse
      Get-ChildItem $lDrivePath -force -include *.xlsx, *.accdb, *.accde, *.accdt, *.accdr -Recurse
      ? {
         $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5) 
      }
      Select-Object -Property Name, Directory, @{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}}, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, @{N="Location";E={$country}}, @{N='size in MB';E={$_.Length/1024kb}} | Export-Csv 
}
```

However there is no output on the .csv file I assigned to output the information. What is wrong in my code?
Thanks!

Comment: You dont need `split` if you import the csv using `Import-Csv -Delimiter ','. Also in the code you posted you dont parse a File to which `Export-Csv` should output the data to.

Answer (score 1):

There are several flaws within your code:

- The Select has neither an `-InputObject` nor is anything piped to it so there can't be an output
- You should decide whether you treat `C:\temp\Location.txt` as
  a text file with `Get-Content`and a split
  or as a csv with headers
  or without headers and supply them to the import.
- The Get-ChildItem output isn't piped anywhere nor stored in a variable so it goes to the screen.
- Export-Csv needs a file name to export to.

Try this untested script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\26\SO_51038180.ps1
$fileHeaders = @('country','hDrivePath','lDrivePath')
$extensions  = @('*.xlsx','*.accdb','*.accde','*.accdt','*.accdr')

$LocContent = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Location.txt" -Header $fileHeaders

$NewData = ForEach($Row in $LocContent){
    Get-ChildItem $Row.hDrivePath,$Row.lDrivePath -Force -Include $extensions -Recurse |
        Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5) |
            Select-Object -Property Name, 
                Directory, 
                @{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}}, 
                CreationTime, 
                LastAccessTime, 
                @{N="Location";E={$Row.country}}, 
                @{N='size in MB';E={$_.Length/1024kb}}
}
# you choose what to do with the result uncomment the desired

$NewData | Format-Table -Auto
# $NewData | Out-Gridview
# $NewData | Export-Csv '.\NewData.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: BTW dividing by `/1024kb` is equal to `/1MB`